# Sbt, testOptions fro ScalaTest in multi module project

Tags: configuration, arguments, sbt, scalatest

I have a multi module Sbt project. In this project I use ScalaTest and I would like to generate HTML and XML reports while keeping the console output.

I followed this article on a simple project and everything was fine : https://blog.ssanj.net/posts/2016-07-06-write-html-test-reports-with-scalatest-while-retaining-console-output.html

But in my multi module project it seems that the `testOptions` are ignored. Those settings are defined in a common settings definition that is reused in all modules:

```
def settingsCommon: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
  scalaVersion := DefaultScalaVersion,
  scalacOptions ++= Seq(
    "-feature",
    "-encoding", "utf8",
    ...
  ),
  testOptions in Test ++= Seq(
    Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-oDI"),
    Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-h", "target/test-reports"),
    Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-u", "target/test-reports")
  ),
  ...
)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(settingsCommon)
  .aggregate(
    `shared`,
    `module-1`
  )

lazy val `shared` = (project in file("shared"))
  .settings(
    name := "shared"
  )
  .settings(settingsCommon)

lazy val `module-1` = (project in file("module-1"))
  .settings(settingsCommon)
  .dependsOn(`shared`)
```

Inspecting the *testOptions* give this result (that seems ok):

```
sbt:my-project> inspect testOptions
[info] Task: scala.collection.Seq[sbt.TestOption]
[info] Description:
[info]  Options for running tests.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  ProjectRef(uri("file:/home/me/my-project/"), "root") / Test / testOptions
[info] Defined at:
[info]  /home/me/my-project/build.sbt:43
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  Test / test / testOptions
[info]  Test / testQuick / testOptions
[info]  Test / testOnly / testOptions
[info] Delegates:
[info]  Test / testOptions
[info]  Runtime / testOptions
[info]  Compile / testOptions
[info]  testOptions
[info]  ThisBuild / Test / testOptions
[info]  ThisBuild / Runtime / testOptions
[info]  ThisBuild / Compile / testOptions
[info]  ThisBuild / testOptions
[info]  Zero / Test / testOptions
[info]  Zero / Runtime / testOptions
[info]  Zero / Compile / testOptions
[info]  Global / testOptions
[info] Related:
[info]  shared / Test / test / testOptions
[info]  module-1 / Test / testOptions
[info]  module-1 / Test / testOnly / testOptions
[info] ...
```

(`/home/me/my-project/build.sbt:43` is the right line number where I define the options)

**Add in edit:**
Showing the test options looks good too:

```
sbt:my-project> ;reload;show testOptions
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/me/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading settings for project backend-build from git.sbt,plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /home/me/my-project/project
[info] Loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] Resolving key references (26112 settings) ...
[info] Set current project to my-project (in build file:/home/me/my-project/)
[info] shared / Test / testOptions
[info]  List(Argument(Some(TestFramework(org.scalatest.tools.Framework, org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework)),List(-oDI)), Argument(Some(TestFramework(org.scalatest.tools.Framework, org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework)),List(-h, target/test-reports)), Argument(Some(TestFramework(org.scalatest.tools.Framework, org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework)),List(-u, target/test-reports)))

... The same for each modules ...
... Except one that is a Playframework module:
[info] play-module / Test / testOptions
[info]  List(Argument(Some(TestFramework(org.specs2.runner.Specs2Framework, org.specs2.runner.SpecsFramework)),List(sequential, true, junitxml, console)), Argument(Some(TestFramework(com.novocode.junit.JUnitFramework)),List(--ignore-runners=org.specs2.runner.JUnitRunner)), Argument(Some(TestFramework(org.scalatest.tools.Framework, org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework)),List(-oDI)), Argument(Some(TestFramework(org.scalatest.tools.Framework, org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework)),List(-h, target/test-reports)), Argument(Some(TestFramework(org.scalatest.tools.Framework, org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework)),List(-u, target/test-reports)))
```

**Edit 2:**
And `show testFrameworks` display ScalaTest amongs others:

```
[info]  List(TestFramework(org.scalacheck.ScalaCheckFramework), TestFramework(org.specs2.runner.Specs2Framework, org.specs2.runner.SpecsFramework), TestFramework(org.specs.runner.SpecsFramework), TestFramework(org.scalatest.tools.Framework, org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework), TestFramework(com.novocode.junit.JUnitFramework))
```

Despite this configuration I have no HTML reports, only the default XML ones and the "-oDI" argument has no effect.

Comment: What is the output of `;reload;show testOptions`

Comment: I have added the result in the question.

Comment: I have a similar setup and my html files show up in the root target directory, not the directory of the project.  I was able to get that to work by adding this to each of my project definitions:

`settings(Test / testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-h", target.value + "/test-reports"))`

I tried to do `ThisBuild/Test/testOptions += ...`, but I could not figure out how to reference `ThisBuild` on the right hand side of the assignment